# Find words within a dictionary C programming

Tags: c, dictionary, spell-checking

I have a dictionary of words in a text file and I need to find certain words within the text file. Such as words that are made up of the letters { q, a, z, w, s, x, e, d, c, r, f, v,t,g,b} or words that end in {d,o,u,s}. I am looking for a way in which i can do this. Would it be easiest to put all the words into an array? or should I keep it all in the text file? Ive tried the text file approach but am stuck. Heres what I have. Much Thanks!

```
 int size, count;

 char *p;
 char *words[];

 FILE * dict_file;

 dict_file = fopen("MyDictionary.txt", "r");

fseek(dict_file, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
size = ftell(dict_file); // get current file pointer
fseek(dict_file, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
// proceed with allocating memory and reading the file


p = dictionary;
while (p = fgets(p, size, dict_file))
{
   p += strlen(p);

   words[count] = p;

   count++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the text file approach that you tried? It is unclear whether you are stuck with searching for words that meet specific criteria (as implied by your question) or by basic file reading (as implied by your code).

Comment: Im stuck on how to search for the words. In the code I have above, I found the length of my txt file. Im unsure of how to approach an algorithm to finding what words can be created with the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, this is wrong:

```
FILE * dict_file;
fseek(dict_file, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
size = ftell(dict_file); // get current file pointer
fseek(dict_file, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
// proceed with allocating memory and reading the file
dict_file = fopen("MyDictionary.txt", "r");
```

You can't (correctly) use a file until you have opened it, so the middle three lines will definitely produce some unpredictable result. Most likely that size becomes a negative number or zero, both of which will probably upset the following `fgets` calls.

This is not shown in your code, but I expect you are calling `malloc()` or something?

```
p = dictionary;
```

And while you are fixing the above errors, you may want to replace this:

```
  while (*p != '\0')
  {
        p += 1;
  }
```

with:

```
  p += strlen(p)-1;
```

[You may want to remove the `-1` if you actually want a `'\0'` between each string

Now, having said that, I would probably take the approach of having an array of pointers to each string, rather than storing everything in one humongous single string. That way, you could simply move from string to string. You can still use your long string like above, but have a secondary variable with the pointers to the start of each string [and keep the zero, so remove the -1 from the above.

I would then write a function that does "is this string consisting of these letters" and another that does "is string ending with these letters". Both should be relatively trivial if you have some idea of how to generally do string handling.

Comment: Okay thank you a lot! So instead of opening the file after those three lines, I would open it before hand? And im having trouble saving the words within the txt file to an array like you said. Would I save it into an array[size][maxWordLength]. Id have to find the max word length still.

Comment: Well, you could just store the value of `p` after each `fgets()` in your existing code - yes, you need to know how many words are in the file. Or set the the size of the pointer array to a larger value than needed...

Comment: How would I just set p to make an array of all the words? and wouldn't size be the amount of words. The text file has one word per line.

Comment: No, you make an array `char *words[NUMBER]` and then use `p` to set the `words[wordcnt]` for each word (add a count of course).

Comment: Okay sorry for all the questions im new at C, but I would do this within the while loop then?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Perhaps you can edit the question [please retain the existing code, as otherwise the answers already given will become quite meaningless, which isn't a nice thing as an answerer]

Comment: "then use p to set the words[wordcnt] for each word"

Comment: So, like I suggested above, perhaps you can add your latest code to the question above...

Comment: You want to set `words[count] = p;`, not the other way around. And I'm 99% sure you want to remove the `-1` on `strlen()`.

Comment: No, did I suggest that? Of course, you could put use `while(p = fgets(...)` and only have one call to `fgets`?

Comment: Oh so put that instead of the (p != 0) ?

Comment: Remove the first `fgets()`.

Comment: So, you should now be able to print all your words after your loop that reads them. That's a good start...

Comment: Okay and then create functions to find the words with the certain letters as stated above, correct?

Comment: Yes. Always, when programming, write a portion of code, test that it works, then write a bit more... Repeat these steps until done.

Comment: Yes, write a loop printing each entry in `words`.

Comment: so like for(i=0; i>100; i++) printf("%c",words[i]);

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a POSIX compliant system you might want to take a look at `<regex.h>`

This way you could search for your words by regular expressions.
I guess something like:

- `"([qazwsxedcrfvtab]+)[^[:alpha:]]"`
- and `"([[:alpha:]]*[dous])[^[:alpha:]]"`

in your case, but you should be sure to adept them to your specific needs.

```
   int regcomp(regex_t *preg, const char *regex, int cflags);

   int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch,
               regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags);

   void regfree(regex_t *preg);
```

would be the functions to take a look upon then.

You could go with something like:

```
regext_t regex;
regmatch_t *match;

char *pos = p;
int n_matches;

regcomp (&regex, "your-regular-expression", REG_EXTENDED);
n_matches = regex.re_nsub + 1;
match = malloc (n * sizeof (regmatch_t));

while (!regexc (&regex, pos, n_matches, match, 0) {
  /* extract key and value from subpatterns
     available in match[i] for i-th submatch
     ... */

  pos += match[0].rm_eo;
}

regfree (&regex);
free (match);
```

Comment: I've never used the regex.h library but I will look into what your code is doing. thanks a lot!

Comment: Be sure to read the manual pages then `man regcomp` et al. Using them is not as complicated as it may seem first. I hope the example given above might give you a good start.